# How to configure Thin Clients to connect to RDS farm

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, rdp, rds, remote-desktop-gateway

We have recently upgraded our RDS servers to include a Gateway, connection broker, and two session hosts (RDGW, RDCB, RDSH1, RDSH2).  This should allow us to have one session host for sales with their sales programs installed and another for engineers with their programs installed, and also provide a bit of load balancing based on departments.

Everything seems to be working.  We can login to domain.com/rdweb and download the rdp file, then connect to the session host successfully based on which AD group the user is in (sales or engineers).

However, previously when we had just one RDP server we configured all our thin clients to automatically open an RDP file and prompt for login details for the RDS server when switching on the thin client.  The user simply entered their login details and connected to the RDS server.  They could use any thin client to login, i.e. hot desk.

Is it possible to achieve this within an rds farm?  From what I have seen you need to configure the rdp file with the session host/collection you aim to connect to, which prevents hot desking.  I would like the one rdp file to allow you to connect to any collection based on the AD group the user is in.

Comment: check this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/339562/remote-desktop-auto-start-session-on-workstation-login

Comment: thanks but thats not really what I'm looking for, I know how to auto start the rdp file when starting the thin client. What I would like is one rdp file to connect the user to the session host they are assigned to